# Tweet button with tooltip like

Tags: html, twitter

I would like to create a tweet button similar to this one :

[image: tweet button]

I tried this from the doc :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="custom-twitter-widget">Tweet</a><script async src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

But it shows only the button like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't, twitter removed that future so you gotta use this [alternative.](http://twitcount.com/) As they stated on the website.. [image]

http://twitcount.com/

Comment: thanks but I don't need the count I just need it like the image shows in my question (for esthetic's reasons)